# How to configure accessibility in OpenBox for GUI Testing purpose

Tags: accessibility, window-managers, gui-testing

I've got a QT application running in a redhat 6.5 server and displayed in a redhat 6.5 server X, with OpenBox as a window manager.

I want to automatize GUI tests, so I choose ldtp (maybe not the best choice, I'm open to suggestions). Ldtp works with the accessibility tool, for disable people.

My problem is that I can't manage to activate at-spi-registry in OpenBox. When I come back to the gnome desktop, I manage to do it, and ldtp works fine, but that is not what I want.

Can anyone help me ?
Thank you.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to activate at-spi-registry? Step-by-step description would be useful.

Comment: I found the answer but I forgot to edit my message, I will do it and close the topic, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to understand where was the mistake, at-spi-registry need (in my case) a gnome-session to work properly. There is maybe a way for OpenBox to simulate such a session, but I didn't figure it out and if it was possible couldn't be done. I had to keep the testing environment and the production one identical.

So, I took another gui testing tool, name SikuliX. it works perfectly on my platform, it is using OpenCV for image recognition instead of accessibility tool.